# Heroku Deployment of Node.js with Compass + Sass Foundation 3

Tags: node.js, heroku, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

Trying to get my application up and running with SASS + Compass Foundation 3 and am having issues I have already updated to the node.js buildpack on cedar stack. I get the WARNING: No version of Node.js specified in package.json, however I am specifying a version.
I am not sure if this is because I now have a Gemfile and a config.rb file for Compass within my repo but everything is working great on local.

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.1.x"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "express": "2.4.3",
  "jade": "*",
  "mailchimp": "*" ,
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer to this question was that you need to have a ruby file.

Comment: I doubt this is it, but try removing the comma after `"mailchimp": "*" ,`

Comment: Actually that was it, it was invalid json

Comment: Oh, sweet! I forgot how strict the JSON parser was...

Answer (score 0):

Here, adding an answer just to take this one off of the unanswered list ;)

As I (didn't really) suspect, the issue was the extra comma after `"mailchimp": "*" ,`

Comment: I would recommend always doing a test install before pushing changes to Heroku after you've modified your package.json file. By 'test install' I mean remove your node_modules directory, and run `npm install`. Then try to start your app. If something doesn't work, it's not going to work on Heroku.